# By Default, How to set ng-model value to an empty string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

Here is my code :

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input ng-model="myInput.name" />
    age: <input ng-model="myInput.age" />

    <pre>
      {{myInput | json}}
    </pre>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.myInput = {};
      });
  </script>
```

By Default, Empty string is not set to ng-model.

By Default, How to set all of the myInput value to "" ?

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tvT7pI1bDoCl1jwDTUtc?p=preview)

**Update:**

Assume There are more than 100 myInput field. Shall I have to manually set it to ' ' ?

**Update 2:**

Pankaj Parkar directive works well. But Of Course, It set all model value to ' ' . How to set model to empty string only if the model is empty ?  I checked attrs.value == undefined but nothing helps.

Comment: I guess you have mispelled `myINput` in your controller... it should be `$scope.myInput = {}`

Comment: In your controller you set `myINput` to an array. In your HTML you use `myInput` as an object. Please fix your spelling. And is it an array or object?

Comment: @Moid Mohd. Sorry my mistake. pls see now.

Comment: @georgeawg. It can be object or array of object

Comment: Use `angular.forEach`, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach will work on both arrays and objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a directive which will take care of setting a default value to `''`

**Markup**

```
input empty-input ng-model="myInput.name" /> <br> <br>
age: <input empty-input ng-model="myInput.age" />
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('emptyInput', function($parse) {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        //ngModel should be there & it should be of type text
        if (angular.isObject(ngModel) &&
          (!attrs.type || attrs.type === 'text')) {
          var model = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
          model.assign(scope, '');
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Other thing you could loop through object and make each property to `''`. But that has limitation which is, for some property you don't wanted to change the value to `''`. Then the directive way would be preferable rather than adding condition inside your loop.

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jDkoDFYlnE4kb090BcWG?p=preview)

**Set Model to empty string only if model is empty**

```
.directive('emptyInput', function ($parse) {
            return {
                require: '?ngModel',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    var ngModelGet = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
                    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                        if (ngModelGet(scope) == undefined && angular.isObject(ngModel) && (!attrs.type || attrs.type === 'text')) {
                            var model = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
                            model.assign(scope, '');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this directive.

Comment: Hi. One more problem. How to set model to empty string only if the model is empty ? I included attrs.value == undefined but not helps.

Answer (score 3):

there are two ways to do it.

In the controller:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myINput = {
        name: '',
        age: ''
    };
});
```

Or in the view

```
Name: <input ng-model="myInput.name" ng-init="myInput.name=''" />
age: <input ng-model="myInput.age" ng-init="myInput.age=''" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use object literal to initialize your variable `myInput`. This will make sure they are set to empty string upon loading

```
$scope.myInput = {
      name: '', 
      age: ''
    };
```

**Edit**:If you want to initialize all the values in the `$scope.myInput` object, you can use the following JS code:

```
Object.keys($scope.myInput).forEach(function(key, index) {
   $scope.myInput[key] = '';
});
```

Or you can use some library such as the `underscore` or `lodash` to iterate the values in the `myInput` object. I am assuming the data type for all the values in `myInput` object is `String`. If other data types such as `Array` exist, you can insert that logic in the **forEach()** block and initialize the values accordingly.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/3VAyutCtaHWVBCIwAcKJ?p=preview . Can u pls correct me where I made mistake ?

Comment: because `$scope.myInput = {};` is empty in your case, therefore no *keys* available. You need to populate the scope variable with keys then initialize their values to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the following code to get the keys :

```
var attributes = Object.keys(myInput);

for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++){
   myInput[attributes[i]] = '';  
}
```

Then loop through attributes and assign them to empty values and then reassign them back to myJSONObject.
I am assuming your object is a JSON object.