# Can't set default angularjs inputs to be blank

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This seems like a trivial issue but for whatever reason I can't initialize any of my inputs to be blank/empty. Google Chrome is somehow setting the value to an older cached value.

Current view (even after emptying cache and doing a hard reload)

[image]

Empty View (this is what I'm trying to accomplish)

[image]

I've tried the following:

```
<form class="m-t" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" role="form" novalidate>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="login.email" placeholder="Email Address" autocomplete="email" required>

    /* Also tried using ng-init */
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="login.email" ng-init="login.email=''" placeholder="Email Address" autocomplete="email" required>
```

I've also tried setting it to "" in the controller like so:

```
function LoginUserCtrl($scope, $http, $state, user) {

    $scope.loginForm.email = "";
    // console.log($scope);

    ...

});
```

What am I missing? Is this specific to Google Chrome?

Comment: I saw someone use a directive to solve this issue. I think I did something similar. Did you see this SO post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441812/by-default-how-to-set-ng-model-value-to-an-empty-string

Comment: Try adding `autocomplete="off"` to form. Chrome has been annoying lately at being too aggressive with their autofill

Comment: Paurian Unfortunately this no longer seems to work ...

Comment: charlietfl This doesn't work either...Google is making this really difficult

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a result of Chrome's **Autofill** feature. Notice the *blue* background of the form field. That indicates it is an autofill value.

You mentioned that you emptied the cache, but in this case I don't think you opted to erase your autofill cache. Specifically you should look into the **Addresses and more** settings of **Autofill**.

Comment: I want all clients who connect to this page to see an empty field, not just from my local machine.

Comment: If this is indeed what is happening, then I don't think you can control your client's machine because this is a browser-controlled feature. In your case, does clearing the Autofill fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are using form name to set its value empty which is not correct.

try this way in your controller to set empty value:-

```
function LoginUserCtrl($scope, $http, $state, user) {
    $scope.login.email = "";

    ...
});
```